# Getting around "typing.Union is not a generic class"

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

In Python's `typing` module, it seems that anything that is not a [generic](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#generics) type does not support subscripting:

```
>>> import typing
>>> from yarl import URL

>>> StrOrURL = typing.Union[URL, str]
>>> typing.List[StrOrURL]                # OK; List is generic
typing.List[typing.Union[yarl.URL, str]]

>>> SetOrDict = typing.Union[set, dict]
>>> SetOrDict[StrOrURL]                  # Raises
TypeError: typing.Union[set, dict] is not a generic class
```

This will be the case whether `SetOrDict` is defined with `typing.Union` or `typing.TypeVar`.  (In Python 3.7, at least.)

It looks like there is a way to subclass `Generic`, presumably like:

```
class SetOrDict(typing.Generic[StrOrURL]):
    # ...
```

But this will immediately raise `TypeError: Parameters to Generic[...] must all be type variables`.

Is there a way to accommodate the above?  I.e., what is the recommended practice for subscripting user-defined (non-generic) typedefs?

Comment: You really would want to refactor code that accepts either sets or dictionaries, *anyway*.

Comment: Normally I would agree - in this case it's basically just a reminder that the input should support O(1) membership testing @MartijnPieters.  But thank you, I will consider that.

Comment: I'd steer away from trying to capture that in type hinting. If you require membership testing to work, use `Container`. Performance choices are separate from correctness checking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a `Union[...]`, alias or otherwise, as a generic type, no. Your union *contents* are also not generic, you can't state what types a `dict` or `set` object can contain by using `dict` or `set` directly, you'd use [`Set`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Set) or [`Dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.Dict).

You have a new union:

```
URLorStrSetOrDict = typing.Union[Set[StrOrUrl], Dict[StrOrUrl, Any]]
```

Note that a dictionary has *keys and values*, you need to provide information on both. If this used as the input for an API, then consider using the more generic and immutable `AbstractSet` and `Mapping` types; this makes it clear that your API only needs to *read* information.

Personally, I'd look hard at refactoring a codebase that is this muddy about what kinds of objects it can accept. Requiring that an API accepts only sets and existing code has to pass in `set(dictionary)` instead of `dictionary` is not an arduous requirement, or perhaps the API really would work with any *iterable* of `StrOrUrl`.